# Android layout alignment issue - photo doesn't fit card length

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I am developing an android application. I have a card layout with a photo on left side and user details on the right side.

[image: Card layout working fine]

When I change font sizes, the card length changes; but the photo doesn't auto-adjust and the bottom border of the photo is not aligned with the card's bottom border.

[image]

Edit: I can't use `height:match_parent` (photo takes only half length of card) because, I believe, the textView at right gets filled only after that.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="4dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground">     

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:translationX="0dp"
    tools:visibility="visible">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="153dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/dummy_profile_picture" />

        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/bg_tag_success"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/approved"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="22 May 2018 10:12 AM "
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Allison (26)" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="Age: 26"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="B-Tech"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Software Engineer"
            android:textSize="13sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:background="@color/dark_goldenrod"
        android:layout_height="153dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:background="@color/dark_goldenrod"
        android:layout_height="153dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout> </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: don't you missing `>` for `FrameLayout`?

Comment: @makvasic, only in here, not in code. Not sure what happened. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the width and height of FrameLayout to fixed values. Change width and height of FrameLayout to android:layout_height="match_parent" and android:layout_width="wrap_content".

Comment: Height:match_parent doesn't work (photo takes only half length of card) because, I believe, the textviews at right gets filled only after that.Width:wrap_content doesn't work because I have a tag on top that is optional. So, depending on if the tag is visible or not the width of photo changes.

Comment: Then use RelativeLayout instead of FrameLayout. it will save you alot of trouble.

Comment: Okay, sorry. That solved the width issue. But still the photo takes only half of card length.

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="153dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
```

This should do the trick I guess :)

**EDIT**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: match_parent for width won't work because that will take whole width of card for photo. We need to dynamically change height. Height of card is more than 153 when using a large font size. I can increase the height to 160 or so, but then, if a user has small font size, the photo will be much larger than the content on right side.